# TypeScript Array of Callbacks

Tags: arrays, callback, typescript

How would you declare an array of callbacks in TypeScript?

A single callback looks like this:

```
var callback:(param:string)=>void = function(param:string) {};
```

So an array of callbacks should look like this:

```
var callback:(param:string)=>void[] = [];
```

However, that creates ambiguity, since I could mean an array of callbacks, or a single callback which returns an array of voids.

In the TypeScript playground, it thinks it is an array of voids. So, my next though was to wrap it in parentheses:

```
var callback:((param:string)=>void)[] = [];
```

But that doesn't work either.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You'll need to use the full type literal syntax form, like so:

```
var callback:{(param:string): void;}[] = [];
```

This is sort of ugly; if you like you can make a name for it first:

```
interface fn {
    (param: string): void;
}
var callback2: fn[] = [];
```

Comment: Cool. That's much better than the any[] I temporarily had in there. Thanks. =)

Comment: Typescript gets so weird... sometimes you just want to store an array of callback listeners  and you end up with this gibberish in your codebase.